# How can I integrate Emacs org-mode with ctags?

Tags: org-mode, exuberant-ctags

I have been using org-mode to handle a large (and growing) body of code. I would like to use exuberant ctags to help me jump around and to remember function names, etc. but I can't figure out a way to run ctags against an org-mode file. If necessary I could use another tags system as long as it creates an external TAGS file that I can mess with.

Each code block lists the language, so it should be possible to more or less fake ctags into creating a file but I can't find any way to do so.

Has anyone ever successfully implemented this? I found [this](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/20684), but it is a patch for helping org-mode / ctags handle links. I'm not worried about links, I want it to parse my actual code.